# Python - Project Interpreters

Tags: python, interpreter

This question might be a very basic one but still I'm burning my brains to solve it.
I'm on a project that I need to use a library called fancyimpute.
I was using the Python 2.7 project interpreter but for some reason I couldn't use fancyimpute on it. The download never worked out. Even if I downloaded it through `sudo pip install fancyimpute` or `sudo -H pip install fancyimpute` when I would write `import fancyimpute` the interpreter wouldn't recognize. There is probably a reason for that to happen, but I have no idea which one is it.

So I found out that the ideal interpreter for fancyimpute would be anaconda. So I downloaded anaconda, installed it and settled it as my project interpreter. Now `import fancyimpute` actually works (yeaaaah) but many other libraries I was importing in my project do not work anymore (pyGTrends for instance).

My question is: how do I make everything work? Can I use two interpreters in the same project?

Comment: Questions like these usually invoke have one of two answers: a) that something is afoot with your PATH variable which makes `pip` install to a different Python version than you are currently using, and b) to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to isolate different Python environments (though Anaconda does ship with its own copy of the Python 2.7 interpreter and is isolated from the main, so it's not an immediate concern).